# Unable to enter a date into a textbox in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, textbox

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtBalochistanExpireDate" runat="server" MaxLength="50" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>

////CodeBehind
txtBalochistanExpireDate.Text = vehiclerootpermit.BalochistanExpireDate.ToString();
```

Textbox is showing `"mm/dd/yyyy"` as `text` in textfield, it should display `"21/10/2014"` in the textfield which is the value of  `vehiclerootpermit.BalochistanExpireDate`.

**General Information:**

`BalocistanExpireDate` datatype is `DateTime` in SQL SERVER.

Comment: clear specified your problem?

Comment: `<asp:TextBox ID="txtBalochistanExpireDate" runat="server" MaxLength="50" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" DisplayDateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" />`

Comment: its not showing anything just "mm/dd/yyyy" is written in the textfield, although i have check using debugging vehicle.BalochistanExpireDate. does contain the value and it is passing to the textbox, but textbox is not displaying it.

Comment: When is `txtBalochistanExpireDate.Text = vehiclerootpermit.BalochistanExpireDate.ToString();` being executed?

Comment: When a function is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it by removing `.ToString()`

Your code must be like

```
txtBalochistanExpireDate.Text = vehiclerootpermit.BalochistanExpireDate.Date
```

Please share the result as in my case (I have tried your code) your code is cresting a problem as well

Comment: Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'string'

Comment: How come? In my case there is no such Error. Anyways you may try this. `Convert.ToString(vehiclerootpermit.BalochistanExpireDate)`

Comment: Also try the above posted solution by removing the `TextMode="Date"` Property from your textbox tag.

Comment: that is what i am telling you it will convert it to string and pass it to textbox but textbox is dispalying "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: by removing  TextMode="Date" it will run i know it.

Comment: You must have done some thing with Property `BalochistanExpireDate` otherwise your given code is OK. The last thing I can suggest is `vehiclerootpermit.BalochistanExpireDate.Date`. I don't know why it is showing the Error of conversion.